# Propel ORM PHP LIKE * Sentence

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel

I need some help in order to execute the next query. I searched the Propel ORM documentation and haven't found anything related to do a WHERE LIKE query and using "*" to found multiple results:

```
->where('Player.Name LIKE ?*', $filter)
->find();
```

Is there any way to make this query using Active Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propel is built on top of PDO, so the above would still not be valid even when using PDO directly.  So you don't use ? with other characters, instead you concatenate them into the variable, in your case `$filter` should contain your wild-card (i.e. % not *).

So you'd first add it to `$filter`,

e.g.
`$filter = '%' . $filter . '%';`

then the correct syntax would be:

`->where('Player.Name LIKE ?', $filter)`

or do it on the fly:

`->where('Player.Name LIKE ?', '%' . $filter . '%')`